# Why jquery dynamic rows are not posted by form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, laravel, post

Have this HTML:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'service.createNew', 'id' => 'newOrderForm')) !!}

    <tbody>
        <tr id="rowItem">
            <td>#</td>
            <td><input class="serviceItem form-control" name="serviceItem[]"></td>
            <td><select class="serviceType form-control" name="serviceType[]"><option>test</option></select></td>
            <td><input class="description form-control" name="description[]"></td>
            <td><input class="itemCount form-control" name="itemCount[]"></td>
            <td><input class="itemPrice form-control" name="itemPrice[]"></td>
            <td><input class="rowPrice form-control" name="rowPrice[]"></td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-rounded" disabled>x</button></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>



</table>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12 invoice-block">
    <ul class="list-unstyled amounts text-small" align="right">
        <li class="text-extra-large text-dark margin-top-15">
            <strong>Celkem:</strong> $11,400
        </li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-rounded btn-success btn-o pull-right" id="saveOrderButton">
    Vytvořit zakázku <i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>       
</div>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And this jQuery, which adds new row to the last TR

```
$(document).on('click', '#addOrderItemButton', function(e) {

    newRow = '<tr id="rowItem"><td>#</td>';
    newRow += '<td><input class="serviceItem form-control" name="serviceItem[]"></td>';
    newRow += '<td><select class="serviceType form-control" name="serviceType[]"><option>test</option></select></td>';
    newRow += '<td><input class="description form-control" name="description[]"></td>';
    newRow += '<td><input class="itemCount form-control" name="itemCount[]"></td>';
    newRow += '<td><input class="itemPrice form-control" name="itemPrice[]"></td>';
    newRow += '<td><input class="rowPrice form-control" name="rowPrice[]"></td>';
    newRow += '<td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-rounded delRowButton">x</button></td></tr>';

    $('#tableNewOrder').find('tr:last').after(newRow);

});
```

Problem is, that when I submit form, lines added by jquery is not sent by the form. I tried to use `.append()` instead of `.after()` but it does not work.

Comment: Note: all added row `<tr>` has same id. which is illegal html

Comment: Where is the #addOrderItemButton element in your html? Also does the <tr> element added by jquery show up in your html before you submit?

Comment: @Makan :: that button is between    </table> and  <div class="row">, I edited that out.

Comment: where is the `$('#tableNewOrder')` element? it should be inside the form

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved - I just needed to move

```
Form::open()
```

before the `<table>` start.